# How to find the sum and average of values in a map?

Tags: javascript

My goal is to add the numerical values in this map and divide them by the size of the map.  The result is merely the numbers without being added. Here's how my code looks like as of the moment:

```
const problem2 = new Map();
problem2.set('Julie', 13);
problem2.set('Jojo', 10);
problem2.set('Polly', 10);
problem2.set('Jack', 10);
problem2.set('Bruce', 10);

let sum = "";
for (const value of problem2.values()){
   sum +=  parseInt (value, 10) +"\n";
};

sum;
```

Comment: You don't need to call `parseInt()` since the values are already integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go with foreach over the map and sum up. For avg divide through mapsize.

```js
const problem2 = new Map();
problem2.set('Julie', 13);
problem2.set('Jojo', 10);
problem2.set('Polly', 10);
problem2.set('Jack', 10);
problem2.set('Bruce', 10);

let sum = 0;
problem2.forEach(value => sum += value);

console.log('Sum: ' + sum);
console.log('Average: ' + (sum / problem2.size));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use forEach and size property

```
let sum = 0;
problem2.forEach(value => sum += value); // value is problem

let average = sum / problem2.size
```

Comment: What is the 'v' for?

Comment: It's parameter of arrow function, U can name it anything u want, I call it 'v', which means current value of the loop

Comment: @JSNoob no problem ^^

Answer (score 0):

You should not be concatenating the string `"\n"` and `sum` should be initialized to `0` as you are working with numbers. The average is the sum divided by the number of values in the `Map`.

```js
const problem2 = new Map();
problem2.set('Julie', 13);
problem2.set('Jojo', 10);
problem2.set('Polly', 10);
problem2.set('Jack', 10);
problem2.set('Bruce', 10);

let sum = 0;
for (const value of problem2.values()){
   sum += value;
};

console.log('Sum:',sum);
console.log('Average:', sum / problem2.size);
```

Comment: No need to count, `problem2.size()` is the number of elements.

Comment: Combined these two responses and I got what I need. Thanks!

Comment: @JSNoob No problem.

Comment: Okay, sure! :)))

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the `Map` to an `Array` so you can use the `Array.reduce` method.

```js
const problem2 = new Map();
problem2.set('Julie', 13);
problem2.set('Jojo', 10);
problem2.set('Polly', 10);
problem2.set('Jack', 10);
problem2.set('Bruce', 10);

const { sum, avg } = [...problem2] // convert Map to Array
  .reduce((result, [, value]) => {
    result.sum += value;
    result.avg = result.sum / problem2.size;
    return result;
  }, { sum: 0, avg: 0 });

console.log({ sum, avg });
// { sum: 53, avg: 10.6 }
```